# Huge array takes more memory space than it should

Tags: php, arrays, memory

Currently my app uses around 7 MB memory.

The array appears to use 700 KB if I check it size with `strlen(serialize($array))))`.

- If use this array within my app, and check memory usage (with `memory_get_peak_usage()`) I get 14 MB.
- If I don't use it, I get 7 MB.

If this array takes 700 KB serialized, why does PHP need 7 MB for this variable? Or am I doing the benchmark the wrong way?

Comment: What's in this array/object?  Representing the true objects in memory may take far more allocation than is needed for a text version.

Comment: A table of all utf8 characters and their ASCII equivalents. Ok, but 10 times more??

Comment: What if you use `memory_get_usage`? `memory_get_peak_usage` shows you `peak` usage

Comment: @ellabeauty, Can you at least post a snippet of what you have?  You aren't going to get a very specific answer when we don't have a clue about the format of this table.

Comment: with memory_get_usage it's much less: 9 M and 5 M

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You wanna steer away from PHP if this bothers you: http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html. PHP arrays just like some living space.

When possible you could use `SplFixedArray`, but then again who cares about what space a PHP array takes. If you are looking for clean / performance stuff why are you using PHP in the first place (yes this is coming from a PHP guy) :)

Comment: @brad tnx! I need people like you when answering questions on a Saturday night :D

Comment: thanks I`ll try to convert my array to a "SplFixedArray", but it will take a long time :)

Comment: @Petra, Ever seen Hacker Jeopardy at DEFCON?

Comment: With SplFixedArray, the same data takes 12.5 M and slightly less CPU. It's a little better apparently, but not very much. Because the array was multidimensional (255x255), I had to use SplFixedArray::fromArray(...) to assign values to the first level...

Comment: Have you also bothered to read the blogpost? @Brad I will have . Just give me 1:46:59 ;)

Comment: Not entirely, but I understand your point. I can't drop PHP at the moment so I'll have to deal with it's limitations, which thanks to you I understand them better :)

Answer (score 1):

Serialized formats can do some memory optimization because they do not need to have the object exist in memory and to have it fully accessibility. They only keep the integrity of the data, not it's accessibility. If this helps to answer your question a little.